# Why does didHighlightRowAtIndexPath cause scrolling to stop on UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a `UITableView`, and if I implement `didHighlightRowAtIndexPath` and `didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath` in its delegate I get different scrolling behaviours than if I didn't implement them.

Normally, you could tap and hold on a `UITableViewCell`, and it would highlight, and then if you moved your finger up or down on the screen the highlight would cancel, and your table view would scroll in that direction.

If you implement `didHighlightRowAtIndexPath` then the cell highlights but when you move up and down the list doesn't scroll, but the cell will highlight/unhighlight as your finger moves over and out of the cell.

Is there a way to implement my own highlighting behaviour using `didHighlightRowAtIndexPath` while keeping the standard scroll behaviours of `UITableView`?